# Connected triangles are not getting displayed

Tags: opengl

I tried to draw a polygon (using OpenGL library and C++) as a set of connected triangles using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP primitive constant. The code that I wrote was like

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
void init()
{
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,300.0,0.0,250.0);
}
void polygonDrawing()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    int point1[] = {30,80};
    int point2[] = {80,40};
    int point3[] = {120,40};
    int point4[] = {165,80};
    int point5[] = {120,120};
    int point6[] = {80,120};

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
            glVertex2iv(point1);
            glVertex2iv(point2);
            glVertex2iv(point6);
            glVertex2iv(point3);
            glVertex2iv(point5);
            glVertex2iv(point4);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(300,300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(150,100);
    glutCreateWindow("An OpenGl window for a polygon");

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(polygonDrawing);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is : The code is showing the polygon properly but not the connected triangles inside it. Can anyone tell my why this is happening and how to overcome it?

Comment: You're not supposed to see 'seams' in the strip. See: [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml). The strip is 'FILL'ed' by default. Try: `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);` before `glBegin...` for outlining.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brett. It's now working. The strips are now displayed after putting glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE). THANK YOU AGAIN.